# Grouping events in a reactive stream based on begin/end events

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive

I have an reactive stream `Observable<Event>` that I observe and currently it emits its events directly. Based on a BEGIN/END event I would like to group this stream of events with the support of inner groups.

**Input Stream**

I have a stream of events like following:

```
Event(type = Data, groupId = 1)
Event(type = BeginGroup, groupId = 2)   // outer group begins
Event(type = Data, groupId = 2)
Event(type = BeginGroup, groupId = 3)   // inner group begins
Event(type = Data, groupId = 3)
Event(type = EndGroup, groupId = 3)     // inner group ends
Event(type = EndGroup, groupId = 2)     // outer group ends
Event(type = Data, groupId = 4)
Event(type = Data, groupId = 5)
```

*Edit - additional preconditions:*

I added ids to the example data but generally, I don't need the ids. The stream will take care to fulfill following:

- every `BeginGroup` event will at some time be followed by the corresponding `EndGroup` event
- events inside groups (in my example with the same group idea) will *always* be inside the begin/end events inside the stream, so the order is guaranteed (like in the example above)

**DESIRED output stream**

So I make sure that each event is either part of the group above it or has a unique id if it is not part of a real group. I would like to group the above stream of 9 events to following stream of 4 events:

```
Event(type = Data, groupId = 1)
GroupEvent(groupId = 2, data = <LIST of Events and/or sub groups>) with following data:
    data = [
        Event(type = BeginGroup, groupId = 2)
        Event(type = Data, groupId = 2)
        GroupEvent(groupId = 3, data = <LIST of Events and/or sub groups>) with following data:
            data = [
                Event(type = BeginGroup, groupId = 3)
                Event(type = Data, groupId = 3)
                Event(type = EndGroup, groupId = 3)
            ]
        Event(type = EndGroup, groupId = 2)
    ]
Event(type = Data, groupId = 4)
Event(type = Data, groupId = 5)
```

**What I want - logic**

I want to start grouping as soon as an event of type `BeginGroup` occurs until the correct `EndGroup` event occurs and group ALL events between those two events including eventually nested group events. Elements outside of begin/end group events are simply passed through as a single event.

**Here is what I tried so far**

I tried something before asking this question, but I'm coming from java and I even used the window/buffer operator very rarely there and have very little experience with them. I saw there is something like a `GroupByUntil` oeprator in C# so I tried to use this but in my example it does never emit anything.

```
var eventObservable: Observable<Event> = ...

// 1) make the observable hot so it can be resued inside the groupbyuntil operator
eventObservable = observable.Publish().RefCount();
var res = eventObservable
    .GroupByUntil(
        e => e.GroupId, // selector for groups => the group id can be used here
        grp => eventObservable.Where(e => e.GroupId != grp.Key) // stop a group as soon as the group id changes
    )
    .SelectMany(data => data.ToList()) // flatten the observable
    .Select(data => {
        // Convert the list of Events to GroupEvent if it contains more than 1 event
        var list = data.ToList();
        if (list.Count == 1)
            return list[0];
        return new GroupEvent(list);
    })
```

This approach does not work, it simply never emits anything (the `eventObservable` does emit it's items correctly though). Additionally it misses the support of nested groups (theoretically if it would work).

Can someone explain to me how I could solve my problem?

Comment: Do you want grouping based entirely on order/nesting? Or by group id? What if the IDs are out of sync or order?

Comment: Actually, the group id is not relevant and probably not even necessary, the order of events can be taken for granted and is the source for grouping. So I want to group by order actually and start groups/end groups based on events (with respect to inner groups) - added this information to my question underneath my first headline at the end (actually, in my test I even manually added the GroupId with the help of `Buffer(2, 1)` and generated the ids manually and then flatten the stream out again...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code dump first, then explanation.

Data Classes I wrote:

```
public enum EventType
{
    Data,
    BeginGroup,
    EndGroup,
    Group
}

public class Event<T>
{
    public Event(int id, EventType type, T data)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Data = data;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public EventType Type { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set;}
}

public class GroupEvent<T> : Event<T> {
    public GroupEvent(int id, IEnumerable<Event<T>> events)
        : base(id, EventType.Group, default(T))
    {
        this.ChildData = events;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Event<T>> ChildData { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the logical extension method (uses Nuget package `System.Collections.Immutable`):

```
public static class X
{
    public static IObservable<Event<T>> GroupEvents<T>(this IObservable<Event<T>> source)
    {
        return source
            .Scan((groupId: 1, stack: ImmutableStack<ImmutableList<Event<T>>>.Empty, output: (Event<T>)null), (state, inEvent) =>
            {
                if(inEvent.Type == EventType.Data)
                {
                    if (state.stack.IsEmpty)
                        return (state.groupId + 1, state.stack, new Event<T>(state.groupId, EventType.Data, inEvent.Data));
                    else
                    {
                        var newEvent = new Event<T>(state.stack.Peek()[0].Id, EventType.Data, inEvent.Data);
                        var newList = state.stack.Peek().Add(newEvent);
                        var newStack = state.stack.Pop().Push(newList);
                        return (state.groupId, newStack, null);
                    }
                }

                if(inEvent.Type == EventType.BeginGroup)
                {
                    var newEvent = new Event<T>(state.groupId, EventType.BeginGroup, inEvent.Data);
                    return (state.groupId + 1, state.stack.Push(ImmutableList<Event<T>>.Empty.Add(newEvent)), null);
                }

                if (inEvent.Type == EventType.EndGroup)
                {
                    var newEvent = new Event<T>(state.stack.Peek()[0].Id, EventType.EndGroup, inEvent.Data);
                    var newList = state.stack.Peek().Add(newEvent);
                    var newStack = state.stack.Pop();
                    var toEmit = new GroupEvent<T>(newList[0].Id, newList);
                    if(newStack.IsEmpty)
                        return (state.groupId, newStack, toEmit);
                    else
                    {
                        var parentList = newStack.Peek().Add(toEmit);
                        newStack = newStack.Pop().Push(parentList);
                        return (state.groupId, newStack, null);
                    }
                }

                throw new NotImplementedException();
            })
            .Where(t => t.output != null)
            .Select(t => t.output);
    }
}
```

Here's runner code:

```
var s = new Subject<Event<int>>();
var o = s.GroupEvents();

s.OnNext(new Event<int>(-1, EventType.Data, 1));
s.OnNext(new Event<int>(-1, EventType.BeginGroup, 2));
s.OnNext(new Event<int>(-1, EventType.Data, 3));
s.OnNext(new Event<int>(-1, EventType.BeginGroup, 4));
s.OnNext(new Event<int>(-1, EventType.Data, 5));
s.OnNext(new Event<int>(-1, EventType.EndGroup, 6));
s.OnNext(new Event<int>(-1, EventType.EndGroup, 7));
s.OnNext(new Event<int>(-1, EventType.Data, 8));
s.OnNext(new Event<int>(-1, EventType.Data, 9));
```

Results look like you expect in your question.

---

### Explanation:

I took a state-machine approach, which normally means using the `.Scan` method. Our state here is the running `groupId` count, as well as a stack of a list of messages. The top of the stack represents which group we're currently looking to add messages to. Since `Scan` doesn't allow you to differentiate between state and output, our third value to state is an output variable.

I'm using immutable collections because they play nicest with Rx. If you use mutable collections, performance can improve, but you have to be careful about multiple subscription implications.

As for using the built-in operators (`GroupBy`, `Buffer`, `Window`, `Join`, etc.), I don't think any of those will work well with the tree-like, recursive structure that you want. If you were fine with a flatter structure, then `Window` may work, but it would require some work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I thought that there may be a solution with the window operator but your "manual" solution looks quite good as well and does exactly what I want - thanks a lot